# Table adapter, table updating

Tags: c#, sql, search, relational-database, tableadapter

I am trying to do a simple app with which I would update data in a table that is related to other tables. I connected VS to SQL server management in which I made the tables that I need. So far I used table adapter to create a selected view of fields that I need from related tables. In search criteria builder I created a query that searches data from columns and shows all data about that search term.

When I start the app it works, I can search data and it shows everything relevant that I need. But binding navigator save data doesn't work. I tried to make a save button but I failed.

I need the app to save changes to data that user makes but I don't know how to do it. Can somebody help me?

Thank you so much !!!!
Sasa

Comment: include your relevant code here?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make a save button with this code:

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SAŠA-PC\SQLBUTINA;Initial Catalog=KTRaspremanjeTEST;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Raspremanje (RaspremljenoKomada,NovaLokacija,Komentar) VALUES ('" + raspremljenoTextBox.Text + "','" + novaLokacijaTextBox.Text + "','" + komentarTextBox.Text + "')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```